# Chakra UI Modal overlay always cover all screen

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, components, chakra-ui

```
<>
  <Button onClick={onOpen}>Trigger modal</Button>

  <Modal onClose={onClose} isOpen={isOpen} isCentered>
    <ModalOverlay />
    <ModalContent>
      <ModalHeader>Modal Title</ModalHeader>
      <ModalCloseButton />
      <ModalBody>
        <Lorem count={2} />
      </ModalBody>
      <ModalFooter>
        <Button onClick={onClose}>Close</Button>
      </ModalFooter>
    </ModalContent>
  </Modal>
</>
```

I'm using chakra UI component UI package.

Modal overlay always cover all screen. How can I make ModalOverlay only cover limited screen?

Here is an example. Overlay only cover center screen except pink area

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbxEC.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<ModalOverlay marginX="10vw" width="80vw" />
```